Toggle LED notifications automatically
I would like to periodically toggle the LED for notifications on/off.
Would that be possible? Using tasker or some other method.
I'm using Rising OS 4.1 for Samsung S8, it's android 14, the toggle for LED notifications is in the settings > personalize your device > notifications > notification light.

